# Poppler installation

Tags: build, dpkg, poppler

I downloaded the new poppler 0.15 tarball and i built it from source successfully but when trying

```
dpkg -l | grep poppler
```

it outputs

```
ii  libpoppler-dev                                0.14.3-0ubuntu1.1                                  PDF rendering library -- development files
ii  libpoppler-glib-dev                           0.14.3-0ubuntu1.1                                  PDF rendering library -- development files (GLib interface)
ii  libpoppler-glib4                              0.12.4-1ubuntu1                                    PDF rendering library (GLib-based shared library)
ii  libpoppler-glib5                              0.14.3-0ubuntu1.1                                  PDF rendering library (GLib-based shared library)
ii  libpoppler5                                   0.12.4-1ubuntu1                                    PDF rendering library
rc  libpoppler6                                   0.14.2.is.0.14.1-0ubuntu1                          PDF rendering library
ii  libpoppler7                                   0.14.3-0ubuntu1.1                                  PDF rendering library
ii  poppler-utils                                 0.14.3-0ubuntu1.1                                  PDF utilitites (based on libpoppler)
```

So AFAIK this means that the new version is not installed !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dpkg` will only show the binary `*.deb`packages installed if you just `./configure && make && make install` it will not show up in dpkg.

Comment: Thx for your answer .. yes it is not a binary but i want to build evince 2.32 and make use of its new features which require poppler 0.15 so my question is which poppler version will it use .. the new 0.15 or 0.14 ?

Comment: It will use the version installed under `/usr` so you can try `./configure --prefix=/usr && make && make install` . But note that this might break existing packages depending on poppler 0.14.